# How to Draw with your Finger on an iPhone Web App HTML5 - Is it possible?

Tags: iphone, android, html, web-applications

As a webapp, not a native app on the iPhone or Andriod. Is it possible to draw with your finger? If so, how?

Anyone have or can provide a barebone simple example that just loads a blank page?

Thanks

Comment: How about http://tenderlovingcode.com/blog/web-apps/html5-canvas-drawing-on-ipad/ ?

Answer (score 2):

You could use the current cursor position to draw on a `canvas` element the size of the screen.

Comment: Can you provide an example or link?

Comment: I would use [jqtouch](http://www.jqtouch.com/) to grab touch events. I don't have the time to code up an example, and I've never seen it done.

Answer (score 1):

Like @Josh mentioned.  You can use the [`canvas`](http://thinkvitamin.com/dev/html-5-dev/how-to-draw-with-html-5-canvas/) element which is part of HTML 5

Comment: I've googled extensively, but it doesn't seem to work on an iPhone as the touch isn't registering. Which is why I was hoping someone had an example or has accomplished something like this before? Remember this is for a mobile device, and I want drawing to be touch based. Thoughts?

Comment: I haven't tried HTML5 on the iPhone (or iPad).  Since HTML5 is still "work in progress" and looking at other questions here on stackoverflow, I don't think it's going to be a solid app.

You can try to run some of the HTML5 demo apps on your iPhone and see how they render, etc.

http://html5tutorial.net/general/new-canvas-examples.html

Some issues with HTML5 on iPhone/iPad
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2998941/iphone-ipad-html5-canvas-filltext-problem
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2878580/bug-in-ipads-html5-canvas-drawimage-implementation